# how to transfer data between Azure tables and Hadoop on Azure

Tags: azure-table-storage

I would like to import data from Azure table and then export to Hadoop cluster on Azure.
Currently I am downloading the data from Azure table into .csv and then uploading the .csv to Hadoop cluster. I want to know whether there is any way to do it directly.

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 1):

I have written a HiveStorageHandler which will let you create Hive Table which are backed by Azure Storage Tables. It's available on github:

https://github.com/simonellistonball/hive-azuretables

Note that you will also need the [Microsoft Azure SDK for Java](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/) in your hadoop classpath for this to work. The easiest way to do that is probably to install it somewhere central like /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/.

If you do a mvn package on my repo, you should get something you can then load with a hive ADD JAR. The [Readme](https://github.com/simonellistonball/hive-azuretables/blob/master/README.md) for the repo contains a sample query showing how to create a Hive table that connects to Azure.